# Hide mouse cursor in ubuntu (for touchscreen)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, xorg, cursor, touchscreen

I've recently got a tablet pc (JooJoo.com]) and I've got it nicely set up with Jolicloud - an Ubuntu derivative like Mint - (thanks to [the joojoo forum](http://www.thejoojooforum.com)) but I can't hide the mouse cursor in Gnome.

Now, I've read so much about tips and tricks on how to hide the cursor with terminal, X and gconf tricks in my Googling, but NOTHING works!

How do I do this definitely?

**Edit:** Unclutter is not what I want, nor is changing the root X cursor satisfactory, because it is overridden by whatever toolkit you are using.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved!

This post details how to create a blank cursor theme and use it with xsettings. I never see my mouse anymore!

http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-general-1/manually-setting-x-cursor-or-theme-doesnt-work-no-errors-700965/

Answer (score 0):

Another Option is to set the cursor theme in ubuntu to an invisible theme.
For that I created one. You can find it here
https://github.com/gysi/ubuntu-invis-cursor-theme